# Can every quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ be extended to a cyclic extension of degree 4?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Suppose $K$ is a quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. Does there exist a Galois extension $L/K$ such that $Gal(L/K)\cong\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ ?